# How do I match motor and battery leads on a generic e-bike conversion kit?

Tags: electric-bike

This is for a "Generic Add-on Motorize Bike 48v 1000w 26 Inch Front Wheel Electric Bicycle Motor Conversion Kit."

How do I find connectors to the motor and battery that are compatible before I buy them for this bike? I am not talking about voltage or wattage. I just want the connectors to fit without splicing.

Comment: Unless you have photos or part numbers for the connectors you can't. How can we tell you based only on "generic kit"?

Comment: Go to an auto parts place.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll just have to wait until the kit arrives, but I am glad to know people on this site help with questions.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the info you've presented, its "cross your fingers and hope"

Can you tell us anything further about the motor, motor kit?  Even a manufacturer could help.

My ebike kit used 7 pin DIN connectors with a screw-on barrel lock ring.  The battery connectors were generic automotive spade connectors.

If you're choosing a connector, then voltage and current (ie wattage) is relevant, as is whether you want to hot-connect them.  Plus you need something that is water resistant and vibration tolerant.  (note spade connectors are neither of these... guess how I know that!)

Final thought - you're talking about a kit.  In my mind a kit comes with everything you need to do the job, possibly excluding batteries themselves.  However any parts not included will be common and well-described.

And what's wrong with a splice?  A properly-done connection will outlive the wire.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I think that I am going to go with your final thought and wait until the kit arrives. I will tell you more about the motor and the kit when it arrives. I was just wanting to get everything prepared before it arrived and I think that is asking too much.